# How to download file with its original name instead of unique name?

Tags: php, filenames

Currently my file uploading progress is following:

1. User select a file to upload.
2. Then I rename user uploaded file to unique name with following PHP code:

   > ```
   > $ext = explode('.', basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']));
   > $file_name1 = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext)-1];
   > ```
3. After that I just upload this unique file to my 'upload_doc/' directory.

Now there are a option in my script to download this uploaded file.  To download, I'm just calling this `unique` file name from 'updload_doc/' directory and download it.

Now it's showing my regenerated file name when I download a file.

Is there any way to download this file with its original name instead of `unique` file name?

**Note:** I can upload original file to a directory but what happened if the user uploads the same file?  Can you guys tell what is the trick to do this?

**My file downloading system :**

**This is a button for Download:**

```
<a target="_self" href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $rselectfile1['file_name']; ?>"><input type="button" name="download" value="Download" class="submit"/></a>
```

**This is download.php file**

```
<?php
@session_start();
//require_once("config.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['front_username']) && isset($_SESSION['front_username']) == "" &&
    !isset($_SESSION['front_password']) && isset($_SESSION['front_password']) == "" &&
     !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) == "") {
    header("Location:login.php");   
    exit();
}


$file_get = $_GET['filename'];

$tmp = explode(".",$file_get);
switch ($tmp[count($tmp)-1]) {
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "docx":
  case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "csv":
  case "xls":
  case "xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  case "tif":
  case "tiff": $ctype="image/tiff"; break;
  case "psd": $ctype="image/psd"; break;
  case "bmp": $ctype="image/bmp"; break;
  case "ico": $ctype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_get."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("upload_doc/$file_get" );


?>
```

Comment: Sure, just set a variable for the name before you rename it.

Comment: `$filename = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];` as per http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=449

Comment: What @Fred-ii- said, but you'll have to track it somewhere. Alternatively, you can include the original name as part of the unique name, but with a seperator, making it easy to re-parse.

Comment: @TecBrat No I don't want to mix it with original and unique id.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what happen if i set a variable for the name ? Do you mean I've to save this file twice ?

Comment: You'll have to 1) include the name with the hash (You rejected this one), 2)Keep the two names in a database or 3) Keep the two names in a flat file. 4)...?some other cross-reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just prefix the filename with the hash instead of replacing it. This way original filename is preserved. So your code would look like:

```
$file_name1 = md5(uniqid()) . '-' . $_FILES['file1']['name'];
// Example: b4b34d95b44ea3ebaa125508fd51dd44-image.jpg
```

On download, you could just remove this hash from the filename:

```
$file_name1 = substr($file_name1, 33);
// Example: image.jpg
```

And then set the filename like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name1 . '"');
```

Comment: Oh, you were 13 seconds faster :)

Comment: @Gergo Erdosi It's could be trick but now sure is it working or not. I'm trying it.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to preserve the original filename. One of the main reasons to rename uploaded files is to ensure that filename doesn't contain "bad" characters. I highly recommend to use the DB for storing original filenames.

Comment: Then is there any problem if there are a file called '`image.jpg' twice ?

Comment: What? Where do you mean?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy What would be a bad character? And how would it cause a problem?

Comment: @Shibbir No, there shouldn't be a problem. Filenames are prefixed with unique hashes with this code.

Comment: @GergoErdosi For example characters with diacritics, characters from non-english languages, characters which are allowed in Windows filesystems but not in Linux filesystems etc.

Comment: @GergoErdosi So which file name will be save to my directory ? is it `uniqueid-image.jpg` ?

Comment: @Shibbir Yes, like this: `b4b34d95b44ea3ebaa125508fd51dd44-image.jpg`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Ok then if I remove this hash when download this file How php recognize exact file name ? Because php is downloading the file from my directory not database.

Comment: @GergoErdosi check my updated question. I uploaded my script.

Comment: @GergoErdosi I tried with your code. When I'm open the file after download the file then the file is empty or is not opening

Comment: How do I do this when creating a download link for multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Just save both original and unique filenames to the DB when the file is uploaded and then in the download script select the row from the database using the unique file name and set its name to the original name.

Original file name is stored it his variable in the uploading script:

```
$_FILES['file_input_tag_name']['name']
```

To set custom filename of the downloaded file, just set the right header field:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $original_filename . '"');
```

Comment: Check my updated question. I uploaded my script. You said get the original file name when downloaded. But my file is save to directory with unique name then how can i get original file name ?

Comment: You have the original filename in `$_FILES['file1']['name'])`, you are already working with that (you extract a file extension).

Comment: Also @Fred-ii- have mentioned that in the comment of your question 2 days ago.