# Give anchor text name to the pdf file that it links to while downloading

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, download

I want to download some files from this page http://seiaa.gujarat.gov.in/ under section "EC granted". Now when I download each file I get the file with some different name. I want to download the file while retaining its original name as shown on the link. How can it be achieved? 
Can it be achieved by copying the value of text node of anchor tag to its name ? or are there any other solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457485/how-to-download-file-with-its-original-name-instead-of-unique-name this may help you.